# MySQL error 1036: table is read only

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When im trying to insert a record to the table using phpmyadmin it gives me

```
#1036 - Table 'sch_portfolio' is read only
```

I saw in some articles they said that this could happen if the owner of this table is somthing other than mysql. so i set the owner as mysql and restart the server. Still im getting the same error. any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 mysql mysql     4096 Jul 13 15:27 schooltap
```

Comment: One assumes that the `mysqld` process is running under the `mysql` user.  Does that user have access to enter every directory along the filepath?  Has the MySQL user as which you are connecting to mysqld been granted permission to write to the table?

Comment: Does this happen to only one table/database or to all? Maybe the MySQL server is in read-only mode, which is frequently the case for replication slaves - check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_only.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One needs super user privs to do this, most commonly sudo is used to acheve this.

in order too Change the owner of the files.

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Reboot Mysql for the changes

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

who owns `sch_portfolio` and what group are they in, should be mysql:mysql. you'll also need to restart mysql for changes to take affect

also check that the currently logged in user had GRANT access to update

The MySQL server is running as `user mysql` and not as the user I logged into it with. In order for it to access files that have user only rights they must be owned by user `‘mysql’` since that is what the server is running as. Make sure the folder and files used by mysql belong to the user ‘mysql’. These files are located in the `/var/lib/mysql` directory. The directory itself should also belong to `‘mysql’`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but i already did that. still im getting the same error.

Comment: /var/lib/mysql it self is own by mysql. and the user group is also set as mysql. How do i check weather the currently logged user have the GRANT access to update ?

Comment: select * from information_schema.user_privileges where grantee like "'user'%";

Comment: and "chmod 755 /var/lib/mysql"

Comment: It worked on my Mac with a different address where my /mysql folder exists

Answer (score 36):

Make sure you have not set
innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf

Comment: ^ THIS solved my problem when none of the other suggestions helped at all. Thanks a tonne!

Comment: @dklovedoctor  I tried this and it started working but the issue i am facing is that i can't insert or update any table as its giving me error
#1036 Table "......." is read only

Comment: Great! I forgot that I had enabled that! YThanks for the advise!

Comment: @dev_khan i think i may not help you with that. However you can check mysql folder permissions ...

Comment: Same issue. I was about to end my life. Thanks.

Comment: if I remove innodb_force_recovery form my.cnf — mysql would not start back. Only when this ooption is set to 5 it srtarts

Answer (score 5):

According to me, this is because of storage engine .
If you `select storage engine as MRG_MYISAM` then that will make your table only `readable`, you can't insert data.
So, `select myisam as storage engine` ..

Answer (score 2):

i had a similar problem and the solution for me was to change the owner/group of the table files to mysql.
you can do two options

### 1

for first you have to go in your server and get privilegies

```
sudo su
```

and then i went to the hidden folder mysql doing:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/
```

and then i ran this command:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql *
```

and this will solve your problem

then to see if it works you have to reboot the mysql

```
service mysql restart
```

### 2

or you can simply go to phpmyadmin then to your database select all the tables
[image]
and then you have to select option repair[image]
(sorry i got phpmyadmin in italian)
you can do this also in bash,

and this will work!
if no option work try to reinstall mysql

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that in my case, this was caused by a hidden anti malware antivirus Bytefence (probably, it was bundled with something else). The problem was gone after uninstalling this antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Storage Engine so you don't have to replace settings. If you set it to **InnoDB** you're problem sould be solved. ( Changing it can be don in the operations tab in phpmyadmin)