# MySQL not letting update

Tags: mysql

My BBS forum was suddenly not functioning as usual. It is shown as follow. I  hope to have your help to let me know why suddenly this LAMP hosting was suddenly not letting update. I don't see any user right privilege prevent this from running. Does anyone have a clue?

BBs! info: MySQL Query Error

```
User: admin
Time: 2015-7-30 2:50pm
Script: /bbs/index.php

SQL: UPDATE [Table]crons SET lastrun='1438239006', nextrun='1438290000' WHERE cronid='5'
Error: Table '[Table]crons' is read only
Errno.: 1036
```

Comment: This is because user does not have Write permission to the table. Try updating the user privileges.

Comment: User must have at least UPDATE rights for that table or it can be file permission problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629407/mysql-error-1036-table-is-read-only