# Read Only Table

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I Have a page that runs an ajax query every 15 seconds, it runs well a couple of times displays the table it is supposed to display every 15 seconds but, After a couple of succesful displays it shows this message which i can't really decipher or 
[image]

Comment: Don't post your errors and code as image, please.

Comment: What database are you using? I am a little surprised to see the directory `c:\xampp\tmp\` being used for a location to hold a database

Comment: mariaDB I'm am running the page on a local network for now

Answer (score 0):

1- Make sure MariaDB is run by superuser.

2- Make sure you have **not** set `innodb_force_recovery > 0` in `my.cnf`

3- Make sure you are using `innoDB` as engine instead of `MRG_MyISAM`, which is default one. `ENGINE=innoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

Reference1: https://emiksan.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/solved-mysql-error-1036-table-is-read-only/ 
Reference2: [MySQL error 1036: table is read only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629407/mysql-error-1036-table-is-read-only)

Also see: https://itpundit.blogspot.com/2017/11/got-rid-of-1036-table-is-read-only.html